# Changing to ASCII code and represent percents in JAVA

Tags: java, ascii

I am trying to read a string by commandline argument and divide them into character and then show the percentage of specific character included.
For example, if the input is `abaa`, the output should be:

```
65(ascii) 75.00
66(ascii) 25.00
```

Here's the code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;

public class converting {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner words = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        while(words.hasNextLine()) {
            for (char c : words.toCharArray()){
                if (map.containsKey(c)){
                    map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
                } else {
                    map.put(c, 1);
                }
            }

            //print percentages
            for (char key : map.keySet()){
                System.out.println(key + ": " +
                        (map.get((int)key).doubleValue() / words.length() * 100) + " %");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have done with showing ASCII code but what should I do for 
representing the percentage?

My code also has the following errors when compiling:

```
converting.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    Scanner words = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                                    ^
symbol:   class File
location: class converting
converting.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
                                      ^
symbol:   class HashMap
location: class converting
converting.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    for (char c : words.toCharArray()){
                        ^
symbol:   method toCharArray()
location: variable words of type Scanner
converting.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    (map.get((int)key).doubleValue() / words.length() * 100) + " %");
                                             ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable words of type Scanner
4 errors
```

Answer (score 2):

You could count the occurrences of the chars in a Map like so:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "To be or not to be.";
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        //count chars
        for (char c : word.toCharArray()){
            if (map.containsKey(c)){
                map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        //print percentages
        for (char key : map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " [ASCII " + (int)key + "]: " 
                + (map.get(key).doubleValue() / word.length() * 100) + " %");
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
  [ASCII 32]: 26.31578947368421 %
b [ASCII 98]: 10.526315789473683 %
r [ASCII 114]: 5.263157894736842 %
T [ASCII 84]: 5.263157894736842 %
t [ASCII 116]: 10.526315789473683 %
e [ASCII 101]: 10.526315789473683 %
n [ASCII 110]: 5.263157894736842 %
. [ASCII 46]: 5.263157894736842 %
o [ASCII 111]: 21.052631578947366 %
```

Comment: Is it correct if I add
Scanner words = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
  //reading text file
while(words.hasNextLine()) {
for reading text file?

Comment: Casts are bad! You can simply do `map.get(key).doubleValue()`

Comment: @DanielPark Yep, should be.

Comment: @Michael Well, OK, but it's not a risky cast, as it's just from int to double. But ok, you could also just use a Map of <Character, Double> for that matter. I edited the code and used doubleValue() anyway - thanks for the hint!

Comment: But the thing is that I have to show the ascii code as well.

Comment: @DanielPark You can just cast the value of `key` to an `int` to get the ASCII value of the character.

Comment: @Michael _"Casts are bad!"_ , 41 mins ago ;) No you're right. This is a good example for when you need a cast.

Comment: Haha, I did notice I was being hypocritical. Avoid them when you *can*, use them if you *must*.

Comment: @DanielPark i added the output of ascii code to my example

Comment: with the code above, I cannot read the file and the compiler shows errors as I have mentioned above

Comment: @DanielPark Did you import Map and HashMap? You need those imports. I added the code of a complete class so you can see. There should be no errors - everything runs fine, here.